# vscode and python 3

Tags: python-3.x, visual-studio-code

When using VSCode to editing Python 3 code, it renders new features in Python 3 as invalid syntax. This includes: type hints, async stuff.

In Pycharm, one can specify a customized Python interpreter used for this project. Is there a way to do something similar in VSCode?

Comment: you can set the python interpreter using  `"python.pythonPath": "/path/to/python"`  in File>Preferences>Settings.

Comment: thanks. I found something better (`python.venvPath`) following your path.